# Javascript xmlHttpRequest object detection vs try..catch

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, try-catch, object-detection

When checking whether a particular browser supports AJAX, object detection is what I usually do:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
    xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

However whenever I take a look at codes written by the developers who are more senior, it is more likely that I would see a try-catch block instead:

```
try {
   xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    //IE 
}
catch(e)    // if not IE
{
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
}
```

I know that some people say try..catch is slower, however if this is pretty much only a matter of preference, is there a convention/more "standard" way to do this? I was also in the same situation long time ago when I was deciding between innerHTML(not standard) vs DOM(standard). Thank you for your time. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about 
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

XMLHttpRequest is preferred if it fails, it uses ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP").
Much more elegant and dry.

Comment: yeah, but "elegant" doesnt mean "standard", the same thing as innerHTML operation which is "faster" than DOM traversal, but not considered a "standard" way :)

Comment: This is more of a standard. This is similar to how jQuery does it. And its the safest.   `function createStandardXHR() {
 try {
  return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch( e ) {}
}

function createActiveXHR() {
 try {
  return new window.ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" );
 } catch( e ) {}
}

xhr = window.ActiveXObject ?
 function() {
  return createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
 } :
 createStandardXHR;`